# About Frameworks

Tags: php, zend-framework, kohana

I have been for a long time looking into .. what is the best framework and I had found numerous answers, but now my question is different, I really would like some answers on what is the easyest way to start with a framework and wich framework is most indicated to start.
I got the problem of repeat my job over and over again, no problem, but I'm tired, very tired...  I know so many programmer one day got the same as me, and found a solution, I would like to talk a little bit about this..

I heard about Zend Framework (but its a huge framework), and I had had used Kohana MVC Framework for a while (on a project).

Since now I m very  thankful for any information.

Comment: Hi Fernando, not sure there is a 'best' framework; it's probably a matter of opinion. It also depends of the project that you are working on; you mentioned that Zend is too big and that you have used Kohana... what do you think about the two of them? I think the only way to find your perfect fit is trying several and comparing them. Some will be better for different projects so knowing more than one can also be beneficial.

Comment: Yeah Josmas, Thanks for your opinion. I have a tiny experience on Zend, I had worked with my partner on a project where he was using Zend Framework, but it was so difficult at that moment to use it, and my job was only to fix things inside the program, some logic, etc.. 
But in Kohana was a little bit different, I like th style kohana do the things inside.. and is very easy to install and use in almost every host.. and Zend is not so easy to setup.. 
I had started to work with PHP OOP and the best is to start to use a framework, thats why I asked...
Thanks Again. Very Useful answer

Comment: zend is fun to use, really. i have use CI that was parent of konoha. yes zend need a larger learning curve than konoha. but once i understand little about zend, i officially use zend only, no more CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in my opinion there's not a best framework It always depends of your requirements, your knowledge and your job's orientation, there are oriented to specific software applications, mobile devices, web applications for example if you develop web applications there are many frameworks in different flavors some based on PHP some on Java some supports multiple languages as .NET, you have to take in mind the programming languages you manage, for example I'll give a try to web2py that let you develop web apps in python. You'll find out whats the best framework for you giving a try to those related to your requirements. In the end all frameworks try to give the programmer all the tools letting him focus in software requirements. If you got all the tools you wanted in the way you like it, then you got it.

Comment: Hey Fernando, I just found this article for you! oriented for PHP developers, take a look and good luck: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-fwk1/

Answer (score 6):

> Best Framework = (Code quality + Docs
>   + Community + Extensions)/(Your skills + Project requirements)

So, there is no absolute champion, all depends on current project and your knowledge.